# Missing Files in Ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cmd

I have never used Ionic or Cordova before in my life, and I have been experimenting with it for the last couple of days.

When I run cmd and create a new project I see that some folders are missing when I compare it with some projects that I found online.

When I type in cmd `ionic start "name" blank` the file that has been created is missing the files hooks, plugins, and www.

Can anyone explain to me why this is happening?

Comment: Which version of ionic you are using ?

Comment: It's not supposed to contain these files until you start building your project. Only the src folder is important. Start by running the command ionic serve. And next time please follow a the getting start or a proper tutorial before asking these kind of questions.